# Java InputStream wrapper which limits the nuber of read bytes

Tags: java, inputstream

We need to have a process "peek" into the incoming InputStream and using a JSON streaming parser and ensure then no more then XXX bytes are read (i.e. we NEVER want to read past byte XX).
Ideally this should come in the form of an InputStream wrapper that throws some kind of "soft" exception

```
InputStream limited = new SizeLimitedInputStream(realInputStrea, 500000); // max 500000 bytes
try {
    // peek the input
} catch (SizeLimitReachedException e) {
   // that's ok
}
```

I've been looking into existing libs or JDK to avoid writing this from scratch but I don't bee which's the best starting class for this

Comment: Not sure whether it supports "soft" exceptions throwing: https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#limit(java.io.InputStream,%20long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One from Apache James on Github https://github.com/k4200/openmailarchiva-server/blob/b42f9e4f2b5b0fba9cae291fdfcaa1fc23ae5fa0/src/org/apache/james/util/SizeLimitedInputStream.java

Comment: solution from @fluffy using Guava is more complete but gives end of stream instead of exception